# Как реализовать имитацию процесса асинхронно?

Tags: python, asyncio

Здраствуйте, есть такая схема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где первый элемент это очередь вместимостью 6 элементов, а дальше 2 обработчика, суть в том, что с какой-то рандомной задержкой (1-2 секунды) мы запускаем в очередь элемент и если один из обработчиков пустой, то выпускаем элемент с очереди в обработчик, где он задерживается на 5 секунд и выходит, но пока обрабатываются элементы в обработчиках, очередь наполняется и по мере выхода из обработчика элементов в него заходят новые и так определенное кол-во времени (если очередь переполнена, новые не заходят). Я хочу это реализовать с помощью библиотеки asyncio, но не могу сообразить, как сделать это, ибо вначале нужно сформировать весь список тасков, а только потом его асинхронно запустить, но в данном случае его заранее сгенерировать не получиться. Был бы очень благодарен за помощь в реализации

Comment: Схема ничего не проясняет. Но если по тексту - вам нужна очередь одна штука c maxsize=6  и 2 цикла - цикл добавления с рэндомной задержкой добавляет в эту очередь, а второй цикл выгребает. В цикле добавления `await put()` не позволит добавить 7й элемент и будет ждать освобождения места в очереди, а в цикле извлечения вешаете семафор для ограничения в 2 обработчика.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю лучше использовать методы ооп и подогнать маршруты, обработчики и общую систему в разные классы, потом через методы реализовать прогон элементов и ловить время последнего события